# Changing units in QGIS: degrees to meters

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, latitude-longitude, units

I have a global map with CRS WGS84-EPSG:4326 and I want to calculate the area of my polygons. From what I read, to change the unit from degrees to meters I need to change my CRS. However, there is no global system for this.

Is there any solution to change the unit from degrees to meters for a global map?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are a few projections that you can use:

Equal-area world map projections with poles represented as points

- Mollweide
- Hammer (or Hammer-Aitoff)
- Boggs Eumorphic
- Sinusoidal

Equal-area world map projections with poles represented as lines

- Eckert IV
- Wagner IV (or Putnins P2')
- Wagner VII (or Hammer-Wagner)
- McBryde-Thomas flat-polar quartic
- Eckert VI

http://projectionwizard.org/